# How to declare and define methods and closures in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

How to declare a method inside a closure.Or which is better to use method or closure.
I have a closure and in that closure i have a method to call and i defined method as

```
   def getBindedGenes(Long colId)  {
   ........
   }
```

But when i used codenarc plugin for code review it is showing the rule as GrailsPublicControllerMethod and the message as The Grails controller has a public method getBindedGenes. This should be a closure property or moved
What is the cause and what is happening exactly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

I think CodeNarc is warning you that your controller actions must be public closures, not public methods. Given that you can't use a public controller method as an action, there's probably no good reason to have one.

### Grails 2.0 Update

Since Grails 2.0, public methods of controllers can be used as actions, and if fact, it is now recommended to use methods instead of closures.